# KIE Workbench- Uploading Java Class For Use in Guided Rule

Tags: drools, business-rules, drools-guvnor, kie, kie-workbench

I'm somewhat new to drools. I'm using KIE workbench running on tomcat 8. I would like to upload a .jar file containing a Java class I wrote in Netbeans to Drools/KIE workbench THEN use it in the guided rule section of the workbench. I've figured out how to upload the .jar containing the class to my project and include it as a dependency, I've added it to project package whitelist. I am able to use this uploaded object in a new DRL file (new item > DRL file) where I write a rule by hand, but I'm unable to see or use this data model/object in parts of the wb like the guided rule creator (new item> guided rule) or tests (new item> test scenario).

Anyone have any idea if this is possible or know how to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the 'Data Objects' tab and import your class using 'New Item' and then picking your class in the dropdown.

[Import Data Objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZdWE.png)